# firefox font bug on middlemouse click

Tags: html, css, fonts

I input some font on site:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'willamette_sfregular';
    src: url('wills.eot');
    src: url('wills.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('wills.woff') format('woff'),
         url('wills.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('wills.svg#willamette_sfregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

In browsers IE9,10,Chrome,Safari,Opera it works perfectly and also Firefox supports it but with some little problem. If you trying to open new link just with left mouse click it all good, the font is using well but if you trying to open new link using mouse3 button the font dissapear changing it to default font, it happens only in Firefox browser (clean, without any adds)
Here link to example - http://www.mediafire.com/download/k7sc10h47qdadmm/fonts.rar

When you open sub.html with mouse3 button font changes to default but when you click to index.html with mouse3 font returned. I understand like that - it works on firefox only if font stay at the same directory as html file is but when you use sub.html which has link to css file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />` it changes font to default when mouse3 click it. Can't imagine how to fix it

---

i'll try to make some code on jsFiddle but to see the problem you should do next: create any folder, then put index.html file and near stylesheet.css file which has code like this - http://jsfiddle.net/YtHAd/ . Then create new folder where you put index.html and styleshee.css , name folder "1" and put on that folder sub.html which has code like this - http://jsfiddle.net/YtHAd/1/ . the font you can get here - http://www.mediafire.com/download/1ok85zsrs41kgim/WILLS.TTF. Take the font and convert it here - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and grab generated filed that has extensions .eot .svg .ttf .woff to you'r main directory where index.html is and check this u'll see the problem on firefox

---

the all files should look like this:

folder/index.html

folder/stylesheet.css

folder/wills.eot

folder/wills.svg

folder/wills.ttf

folder/wills.woff

folder/1/sub.html

Comment: I don't think anyone here is going to download and open a potentially hazardous RAR file that you linked - it would be best set up a jsFiddle if possible instead

Comment: I can't find on jsFiddle any multi pages functions (2 or more pages) and with it you can't see the problem. And yes my rar archive including the most dangerous virus at the world=)

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in an Ubuntu Installation (inside a VM), but please provide a fiddle or the code directly in the question. You should also verify whether you have the license to share the font files. It's also strange that the issue does **not** occur when you open *index.html* from *sub.html*, only the other way around.

Comment: if this is only about clicking on a link with a middle mouse button, you don't really need to set up multiple pages, as it happens only on the original one - or is my understanding or the problem incorrect?

Comment: @Zathrus Writer this bug appears only when middleclicking link on page that has link to css file that has path like that "../../style.css". And when html page has link to css file like that "css/style.css" or even just "style.css" the font working well

Comment: ah, now I see the reason for that RAR file, thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Just put the directory structure on your own website and give us the address. The relative safety of jsFiddle vs other URIs is overrated anyway.